# Using input with datalist as select - how do I open a full list of values if a value is already selected?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

When I use `<input>` together with `<datalist>`, after selecting a value I try to open a complete list of values, only a list of one value opens. At the same time the list can contain many values to search for the desired value using scrolling. It is necessary to make it possible to enter the first few characters to find the desired value. On the other hand, if the user accidentally selects the wrong value, a single option from the drop-down list can be confusing.

```html
<input id="input" list="datalist" />
<datalist id="datalist">
  <option>&nbsp;</option>
  <option>Afghanistan</option>
  <option>Albania</option>
  <option>Algeria</option>
  <option>Andorra</option>
  <option>Angola</option>
  <option>Antigua and Barbuda</option>
  <option>Argentina</option>
  <option>Armenia</option>
  <option>Australia</option>
  <option>Austria</option>
  <option>Azerbaijan</option>
  <option>Bahamas</option>
  <option>Bahrain</option>
  <option>Bangladesh</option>
  <option>Barbados</option>
  <option>Belarus</option>
  <option>Belgium</option>
  <option>Belize</option>
  <option>Benin</option>
  <option>Bhutan</option>
  <option>Bolivia</option>
  <option>Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
  <option>Botswana</option>
  <option>Brazil</option>
  <option>Brunei </option>
  <option>Bulgaria</option>
  <option>Burkina Faso</option>
  <option>Burundi</option>
  <option>Côte d'Ivoire</option>
  <option>Cabo Verde</option>
  <option>Cambodia</option>
  <option>Cameroon</option>
  <option>Canada</option>
  <option>Central African Republic</option>
  <option>Chad</option>
  <option>Chile</option>
  <option>China</option>
  <option>Colombia</option>
  <option>Comoros</option>
  <option>Congo (Congo-Brazzaville)</option>
  <option>Costa Rica</option>
  <option>Croatia</option>
  <option>Cuba</option>
  <option>Cyprus</option>
  <option>Czechia (Czech Republic)</option>
  <option>Democratic Republic of the Congo</option>
  <option>Denmark</option>
  <option>Djibouti</option>
  <option>Dominica</option>
  <option>Dominican Republic</option>
  <option>Ecuador</option>
  <option>Egypt</option>
  <option>El Salvador</option>
  <option>Equatorial Guinea</option>
  <option>Eritrea</option>
  <option>Estonia</option>
  <option>Eswatini (fmr. "Swaziland")</option>
  <option>Ethiopia</option>
  <option>Fiji</option>
  <option>Finland</option>
  <option>France</option>
  <option>Gabon</option>
  <option>Gambia</option>
  <option>Georgia</option>
  <option>Germany</option>
  <option>Ghana</option>
  <option>Greece</option>
  <option>Grenada</option>
  <option>Guatemala</option>
  <option>Guinea</option>
  <option>Guinea-Bissau</option>
  <option>Guyana</option>
  <option>Haiti</option>
  <option>Holy See</option>
  <option>Honduras</option>
  <option>Hungary</option>
  <option>Iceland</option>
  <option>India</option>
  <option>Indonesia</option>
  <option>Iran</option>
  <option>Iraq</option>
  <option>Ireland</option>
  <option>Israel</option>
  <option>Italy</option>
  <option>Jamaica</option>
  <option>Japan</option>
  <option>Jordan</option>
  <option>Kazakhstan</option>
  <option>Kenya</option>
  <option>Kiribati</option>
  <option>Kuwait</option>
  <option>Kyrgyzstan</option>
  <option>Laos</option>
  <option>Latvia</option>
  <option>Lebanon</option>
  <option>Lesotho</option>
  <option>Liberia</option>
  <option>Libya</option>
  <option>Liechtenstein</option>
  <option>Lithuania</option>
  <option>Luxembourg</option>
  <option>Madagascar</option>
  <option>Malawi</option>
  <option>Malaysia</option>
  <option>Maldives</option>
  <option>Mali</option>
  <option>Malta</option>
  <option>Marshall Islands</option>
  <option>Mauritania</option>
  <option>Mauritius</option>
  <option>Mexico</option>
  <option>Micronesia</option>
  <option>Moldova</option>
  <option>Monaco</option>
  <option>Mongolia</option>
  <option>Montenegro</option>
  <option>Morocco</option>
  <option>Mozambique</option>
  <option>Myanmar (formerly Burma)</option>
  <option>Namibia</option>
  <option>Nauru</option>
  <option>Nepal</option>
  <option>Netherlands</option>
  <option>New Zealand</option>
  <option>Nicaragua</option>
  <option>Niger</option>
  <option>Nigeria</option>
  <option>North Korea</option>
  <option>North Macedonia</option>
  <option>Norway</option>
  <option>Oman</option>
  <option>Pakistan</option>
  <option>Palau</option>
  <option>Palestine State</option>
  <option>Panama</option>
  <option>Papua New Guinea</option>
  <option>Paraguay</option>
  <option>Peru</option>
  <option>Philippines</option>
  <option>Poland</option>
  <option>Portugal</option>
  <option>Qatar</option>
  <option>Romania</option>
  <option>Russia</option>
  <option>Rwanda</option>
  <option>Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
  <option>Saint Lucia</option>
  <option>Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
  <option>Samoa</option>
  <option>San Marino</option>
  <option>Sao Tome and Principe</option>
  <option>Saudi Arabia</option>
  <option>Senegal</option>
  <option>Serbia</option>
  <option>Seychelles</option>
  <option>Sierra Leone</option>
  <option>Singapore</option>
  <option>Slovakia</option>
  <option>Slovenia</option>
  <option>Solomon Islands</option>
  <option>Somalia</option>
  <option>South Africa</option>
  <option>South Korea</option>
  <option>South Sudan</option>
  <option>Spain</option>
  <option>Sri Lanka</option>
  <option>Sudan</option>
  <option>Suriname</option>
  <option>Sweden</option>
  <option>Switzerland</option>
  <option>Syria</option>
  <option>Tajikistan</option>
  <option>Tanzania</option>
  <option>Thailand</option>
  <option>Timor-Leste</option>
  <option>Togo</option>
  <option>Tonga</option>
  <option>Trinidad and Tobago</option>
  <option>Tunisia</option>
  <option>Turkey</option>
  <option>Turkmenistan</option>
  <option>Tuvalu</option>
  <option>Uganda</option>
  <option>Ukraine</option>
  <option>United Arab Emirates</option>
  <option>United Kingdom</option>
  <option>United States of America</option>
  <option>Uruguay</option>
  <option>Uzbekistan</option>
  <option>Vanuatu</option>
  <option>Venezuela</option>
  <option>Vietnam</option>
  <option>Yemen</option>
  <option>Zambia</option>
  <option>Zimbabwe</option>
</datalist>
```

Is there any hack that would solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's a crappy solution, but it works.

```js
input.onmousedown = event => {
  // if value is not empty
  if (input.value) {
    // cancel event procedure
    event.preventDefault();
    // hold current placeholder
    input._placeholder = input.placeholder;
    // set placeholder to the value
    input.placeholder = input.value;
    // clear current value
    input.value = '';
    // add flip-flag class
    input.classList.add('flip-value-placeholder');
    // refocus
    input.blur();
    input.focus();
  }
};

input.onkeydown = () => {
  // if input has flip-flag class
  if (input.classList.contains('flip-value-placeholder')) {
    // remove class
    input.classList.remove('flip-value-placeholder');
    // rollback the value
    input.value = input.placeholder;
    // rollback placeholder
    input.placeholder = input._placeholder;
  }
}

form.onsubmit = event => {
  // find all inputs with list by selector
  form.querySelectorAll('input[list]')
    // just to be sure, do a flip reset
    .forEach(input=>input.onkeydown());
  // get form data
  const data = new FormData(form);
  // alert data
  alert(JSON.stringify([...data.entries()]));
  // cancel event procedure 
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
/* recolor placeholder */
input.flip-value-placeholder::placeholder {
  color: currentcolor;
}


/* remove the caret */
input.flip-value-placeholder {
  caret-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input name="country" placeholder="Country" id="input" list="datalist" />
  <datalist id="datalist">
    <option>&nbsp;</option>
    <option>Afghanistan</option>
    <option>Albania</option>
    <option>Algeria</option>
    <option>Andorra</option>
    <option>Angola</option>
    <option>Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option>Argentina</option>
    <option>Armenia</option>
    <option>Australia</option>
    <option>Austria</option>
    <option>Azerbaijan</option>
    <option>Bahamas</option>
    <option>Bahrain</option>
    <option>Bangladesh</option>
    <option>Barbados</option>
    <option>Belarus</option>
    <option>Belgium</option>
    <option>Belize</option>
    <option>Benin</option>
    <option>Bhutan</option>
    <option>Bolivia</option>
    <option>Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option>Botswana</option>
    <option>Brazil</option>
    <option>Brunei </option>
    <option>Bulgaria</option>
    <option>Burkina Faso</option>
    <option>Burundi</option>
    <option>Côte d'Ivoire</option>
    <option>Cabo Verde</option>
    <option>Cambodia</option>
    <option>Cameroon</option>
    <option>Canada</option>
    <option>Central African Republic</option>
    <option>Chad</option>
    <option>Chile</option>
    <option>China</option>
    <option>Colombia</option>
    <option>Comoros</option>
    <option>Congo (Congo-Brazzaville)</option>
    <option>Costa Rica</option>
    <option>Croatia</option>
    <option>Cuba</option>
    <option>Cyprus</option>
    <option>Czechia (Czech Republic)</option>
    <option>Democratic Republic of the Congo</option>
    <option>Denmark</option>
    <option>Djibouti</option>
    <option>Dominica</option>
    <option>Dominican Republic</option>
    <option>Ecuador</option>
    <option>Egypt</option>
    <option>El Salvador</option>
    <option>Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option>Eritrea</option>
    <option>Estonia</option>
    <option>Eswatini (fmr. "Swaziland")</option>
    <option>Ethiopia</option>
    <option>Fiji</option>
    <option>Finland</option>
    <option>France</option>
    <option>Gabon</option>
    <option>Gambia</option>
    <option>Georgia</option>
    <option>Germany</option>
    <option>Ghana</option>
    <option>Greece</option>
    <option>Grenada</option>
    <option>Guatemala</option>
    <option>Guinea</option>
    <option>Guinea-Bissau</option>
    <option>Guyana</option>
    <option>Haiti</option>
    <option>Holy See</option>
    <option>Honduras</option>
    <option>Hungary</option>
    <option>Iceland</option>
    <option>India</option>
    <option>Indonesia</option>
    <option>Iran</option>
    <option>Iraq</option>
    <option>Ireland</option>
    <option>Israel</option>
    <option>Italy</option>
    <option>Jamaica</option>
    <option>Japan</option>
    <option>Jordan</option>
    <option>Kazakhstan</option>
    <option>Kenya</option>
    <option>Kiribati</option>
    <option>Kuwait</option>
    <option>Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option>Laos</option>
    <option>Latvia</option>
    <option>Lebanon</option>
    <option>Lesotho</option>
    <option>Liberia</option>
    <option>Libya</option>
    <option>Liechtenstein</option>
    <option>Lithuania</option>
    <option>Luxembourg</option>
    <option>Madagascar</option>
    <option>Malawi</option>
    <option>Malaysia</option>
    <option>Maldives</option>
    <option>Mali</option>
    <option>Malta</option>
    <option>Marshall Islands</option>
    <option>Mauritania</option>
    <option>Mauritius</option>
    <option>Mexico</option>
    <option>Micronesia</option>
    <option>Moldova</option>
    <option>Monaco</option>
    <option>Mongolia</option>
    <option>Montenegro</option>
    <option>Morocco</option>
    <option>Mozambique</option>
    <option>Myanmar (formerly Burma)</option>
    <option>Namibia</option>
    <option>Nauru</option>
    <option>Nepal</option>
    <option>Netherlands</option>
    <option>New Zealand</option>
    <option>Nicaragua</option>
    <option>Niger</option>
    <option>Nigeria</option>
    <option>North Korea</option>
    <option>North Macedonia</option>
    <option>Norway</option>
    <option>Oman</option>
    <option>Pakistan</option>
    <option>Palau</option>
    <option>Palestine State</option>
    <option>Panama</option>
    <option>Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option>Paraguay</option>
    <option>Peru</option>
    <option>Philippines</option>
    <option>Poland</option>
    <option>Portugal</option>
    <option>Qatar</option>
    <option>Romania</option>
    <option>Russia</option>
    <option>Rwanda</option>
    <option>Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
    <option>Saint Lucia</option>
    <option>Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
    <option>Samoa</option>
    <option>San Marino</option>
    <option>Sao Tome and Principe</option>
    <option>Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option>Senegal</option>
    <option>Serbia</option>
    <option>Seychelles</option>
    <option>Sierra Leone</option>
    <option>Singapore</option>
    <option>Slovakia</option>
    <option>Slovenia</option>
    <option>Solomon Islands</option>
    <option>Somalia</option>
    <option>South Africa</option>
    <option>South Korea</option>
    <option>South Sudan</option>
    <option>Spain</option>
    <option>Sri Lanka</option>
    <option>Sudan</option>
    <option>Suriname</option>
    <option>Sweden</option>
    <option>Switzerland</option>
    <option>Syria</option>
    <option>Tajikistan</option>
    <option>Tanzania</option>
    <option>Thailand</option>
    <option>Timor-Leste</option>
    <option>Togo</option>
    <option>Tonga</option>
    <option>Trinidad and Tobago</option>
    <option>Tunisia</option>
    <option>Turkey</option>
    <option>Turkmenistan</option>
    <option>Tuvalu</option>
    <option>Uganda</option>
    <option>Ukraine</option>
    <option>United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option>United Kingdom</option>
    <option>United States of America</option>
    <option>Uruguay</option>
    <option>Uzbekistan</option>
    <option>Vanuatu</option>
    <option>Venezuela</option>
    <option>Vietnam</option>
    <option>Yemen</option>
    <option>Zambia</option>
    <option>Zimbabwe</option>
  </datalist>
  <button id="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```